# How do I appeal an edit rejection?

Tags: discussion

After reading a Stack Overflow answer, wondering why the code in the answer didn't work, reading quite a bit further on the topic, I discovered that was because of an error in the answer.

I corrected the answer:
[image]
but my edit was [rejected](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/17212771). Both reviewers respond:

> This edit does not make the post even a little bit easier to read,
>   easier to find, more accurate or more accessible. Changes are either
>   completely superfluous or actively harm readability.

I can understand that the edit LOOKS this way, but in reality, it IS more accurate. The original answer is not valid Python code, the edited answer is valid Python code.

How do I appeal?

And is there a way to be notified when revisions are rejected?

Comment: but the answer seems to be about documentation? Not about creating code that can be interpreted by Python.

Comment: Leave a comment with the correction and enjoy the rest of your day.

Comment: The answer states that the code is also a quote. You should not be changing the text or code from a quoted source at all. The only exception would be if the text at the source changed and you edited the quote to match.

Comment: Duplicate on meta.stackexchange: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/113727/168269

Comment: The [Sphinx documentation](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/1.4.8/domains.html#cross-referencing-python-objects), it is not accurately quoted, so it would have been legitimate to fix that.

Comment: To avoid this, try to clearly state why exactly this is an improvement on the post, possibly with a link, either in the edit description or in a comment, to make it a whole lot easier for the reviewers. This is especially useful for edits that correct factual things (since reviewers might not be experienced in a certain programming language).

Comment: The original poster of that edit has now accepted your edit. As @ErikvonAsmuth says, you should assume that the reviewers are *not* subject experts, so try to be as specific as possible in the edit comment.

Comment: Also, if the edit gets rejected, then you could leave a comment to the post with a pointer to the rejected edit, as the author may still approve it

Comment: Yup, just had one of these where I was editing an answer dealing with code that I was the original author and designer of to make the use more idiomatic and to reduce the clutter in the answer.

Answer (score 10):

The edit was minor but in my opinion correct. It might seem to *untrained* eye that this edit was incorrect, but the fact is that there are 2 distinct syntaxes: Sphinx syntax that is rendered into a document

```
.. py:function:: send_message(sender, recipient, message_body, [priority=1])
```

and Python syntax that would be

```
def send_message(sender, recipient, message_body, priority=1):
```

without brackets. The brackets are never correct in the Python code. The author "quoted", i.e. *paraphrased* the Sphinx documentation, without even referring to the *actual page*. In its current state, the post might lead *someone* to believe that there is such a syntax somewhere that would allow writing

```
def send_message(sender, recipient, message_body, [priority=1]):
```

when nothing now, one, or 5 years ago, would have accepted that. Thus Josiah's edit was in my opinion very valid and improved the post by removing confusion.

---

Addendum. In the case of quoting documentation, and the original link not pointing to the exact source of the quote, or the link missing altogether, your edit should also include a more precise link.

Comment: FWIW, i was the original author of that comment and approved the submission, while linking to the original code as well. i  hope that satisfies everyone.

Comment: @anarcat excellent!